# How to get an event for wifi getting enabled or disabled

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager, android-10.0, android-connectivitymanager

What is a way to listen and receive an event when Wifi is enabled or disabled on Android?

Note that I am not looking for connectivity to the internet. I am just looking for an event which says wifi in the wifi settings was enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION) broadcast intent action to check Wi-Fi state.

Add this to your manifest file:

```
<receiver
    android:name=".WifiReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

And use this class for receiving broadcast:

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Check the state here
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you check wifi state inside `onReceive`? Is it possible to do this without writing a new class changing the inheritance hierarchy of my class?

Comment: I have edited my answer to check state in `onReceive()` using [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#EXTRA_WIFI_STATE) key. And you would have to make a BroadcastReceiver class to get that broadcast.

Comment: this won't work if the receiver is used in the manifest because the intent isn't whitelisted, only a runtime receiver can receive it